# how to call javascript function on body load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to call a javascript function when the body loads.
right now i have a function call on the button, but when i add the same to the body load,i am not able to call the function

html:

```
<body onload="bodyload();">
```

javascript:

```
function bodyload(){
    displayFireworks();
    alert("working");
}

function displayFireworks() {
    /*document.getElementById('auto_fire').innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void"  onClick="stopCount(); return false;" title="Stop"  > <img src="image/button9.png" alt="Stop" width="200" height="50"> ';*/
    createFirework(25,187,7,1,null,null,null,null,false,true);
    t=setTimeout(function(){displayFireworks()},2000);
}

function doTimer() {
    if (!poping) {
        poping=1;
        displayFireworks();
    }
}

function stopCount() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    poping=0;
    document.getElementById('auto_fire').innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void"  onClick="displayFireworks(); return false;" title="Auto Start"  > <img src="image/button8.png" alt="Auto Start" width="200" height="50"> </a>';
}
```

Firework()

```
function Firework(oC,startX,startY,burstX,burstY,burstType,nRadius,nParticles,nCircles,allowRandom,obeyBoundaries) {
  var self = this;
  this.oID = 'fp'+(fc.gOID++); // may be unneeded
  var p = '';
  for (var i=0; i<arguments.length-1; i++) {
    p += arguments[i]+',';
  }
  p += arguments[i];
  writeDebug('firework('+p+')');
  this.oC = oC;
  this.o = fc.oFW.cloneNode(!fc.isIE?true:false);
  this.particles = [];
  this.vX = -1;
  this.vY = -4;
  this.x = startX;
  this.y = startY;
  this.allowRandom = allowRandom;
  this.obeyBoundaries = obeyBoundaries;
  this.frame = 0;
  this.tween = [];
  this.active = false;
```

if i call the bodyload with `displayFireworks();` commented, i am able to get the function working, i am able to get the alert box. but when i remove the comment and call `displayFireworks();` i am not able to get anything. how can i do this?

Comment: `displayFireworks()` has some error which doesn't let you got to the `alert`. We need to look at your `createFirework()`  also.

Comment: Some function, `createFirework` maybe is throwing error causing the other functions not to execute. Check console

Comment: Are you getting any errors in dev. tools console? IS it works with "displayFireworks" commented out it may indicate there's some problem with that function.

Comment: @leuquim i am getting ''cloneNode' of null' error.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wfoo2arh/ define them in your `head` before the body load. — `createFirework` is not defined also

Comment: You **still** haven't posted `createFirework`, and what you've just added won't even parse.

Comment: Your `Firework()` function name and `createFirework()` don't match.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i have updated the post.

Comment: Not since my comment above you haven't.

Comment: *Now* you have, but ***still*** no `createFirework`, and still won't parse. Giving up.

Comment: <body onload="bodyload();"> is working fine there is some problem with createFirework it is not finding that function put debugger and check in browser using F12.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have a function named "createFirework" to call and u dont close with } your fireworks function